# SSRS How to can ı make this (stair view)in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting

I am trying to make this view in SSRS but ı couldnt. I want to add child groups but when ı add them they appear as column. How can ı add them like rows?

[image: this]

Comment: Good question, I've grappled with this too but off the top of my head I can't remember how I got round it

Answer (score 1):

When a group is added, by default a new column is added. However, you can simply delete the additional columns, the row groups will still be present.